# how start DragDealer slider value from 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML CODE IS:

```
<div id="notary-slider" class="dragdealer">
      <ul class="list_wrapper">
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
         <li>5</li>
         <li>6</li>
         <li>7</li>
         <li>8</li>
         <li>9</li>
         <li>10</li>
     </ul>
    <div class="handle red-bar">
     <span class="value"></span>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="answer[]" id="no-of-documents" required>
   </div>


 $(function() {
    new Dragdealer('notary-slider', {
    speed: 1,
    loose: true,
    steps: 10,
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
     $('#notary-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 10));
     $("#no-of-documents").val(Math.round(x * 10));
    }
});
})
```

In this js the value of the slider is printing from 0 to 10 but I want the slider value to start from 1 to 10. I have used dragdealer slider. Can anybody help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Initialize `x: 1,` before `speed`.

```
$(function() {
    new Dragdealer('notary-slider', {
    x: 1,
    speed: 1,
    loose: true,
    steps: 10,
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
     $('#notary-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 10));
     $("#no-of-documents").val(Math.round(x * 10));
    }
});
})
```